# Fourier series of the form $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(kx)}{k^{2}+a^{2}}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I have encountered some Fourier series of the form : 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(kx)}{k^{2}+a^{2}}$$
and 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(kx)}{k^{2}+a^{2}}$$
What is the domain of convergence of such series, and what functions -if any- do they represent ?

Comment: They are clearly absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1/(k^2+a^2)$ converges, these series converge for all real $x$.  According to Maple,

$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(kx)}{k^2+a^2} = {\frac {-i \left( {\Phi} \left( {{\rm e}^{ix}},1,-ia
 \right) a-{\Phi} \left( {{\rm e}^{ix}},1,ia \right) a+{\Phi} \left( {{\rm e}^{-ix}},1,-ia \right) a-{\Phi}
 \left( {{\rm e}^{-ix}},1,ia \right) a-4\,i \right) }{4{a}^{2}}}$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(kx)}{k^2+a^2} = {\frac {{\Phi} \left( {{\rm e}^{-ix}},1,-ia \right) -{
\Phi} \left( {{\rm e}^{-ix}},1,ia \right) -{\Phi}
 \left( {{\rm e}^{ix}},1,-ia \right) +{\Phi} \left( {{\rm e}^{
ix}},1,ia \right) }{4a}}
$$
where $\Phi$ is the Lerch Phi function.